# Is there a way to play an .mp3 file without opening a Banshee window?

Tags: 11.10, banshee, mp3

I want to play an .mp3 file without Banshee opening, it will just start on the top bar in the sound icon.
[image: The one with the Sound icon]

For the record I am using Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: for the record you don't have to use Banshee...

Comment: command line: aplay :+

Answer (score 1):

You can play a .mp3 from the terminal with mpg321 (universe). 
You can also create a bash script that will play your .mp3 without opening a window.

- Install mpg321

.

```
sudo apt-get install mpg321
```

- Create a new file with the .sh extension
- Then add this code inside the .sh file:

.

```
#!/bin/bash

mpg321 /PathForMP3.mp3
```

- Make sure your new .sh file have execution privilege. You can use chmod +x or via the nautilus GUI (right click file, properties, Permissions tab, Tick Allow executing file as program box.)

Answer (score 1):

The fastest, simplest way to do this is with [gnome-sushi](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/gnome-sushi/) (a file previewer in the Software Center) Install it and then just select the sound file and tap the space bar. You can preview many files this way, it's pretty cool. You get a little pop-up window like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can always close Banshee window by clicking on 'X'. Music file will keep playing in background.
For alternative- I use Clementine, it doesn't open it's window when you click on music file, but displays it's icon in top bar just like you want it to be.

Comment: if you close the window, the music will stop playing after just ONE song.

Comment: Depends on what's on your play-list. For me it continue playing my next playlist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gloobus (http://gloobus.net/). I use it all the time for different previews. All you need to do is find the mp3 file and press space, it will start playing in a focus window, once you change focus away from it, it will stop.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier method that makes a preview of mp3, wmv, ogg and is valid also for other file formats, like txt, pdf, etc. You can install [Gloobus Preview](http://gloobus.net/) either by the [developers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gloobus-dev/+archive/gloobus-preview) or installing [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/app/gloobus-preview/). You can have a preview of many of your files just by pressing the Space Bar.